# How to handle multiple redirectTo in child if child path not match?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

How to handle multiple redirectTo in child if child path not match?
Please see below example:

```
const APP_ROUTERS: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'admin', 
     children:[
       { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
       { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
       { path: '*', redirectTo: '' },
     ] 
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard/:userId', component: DashboardComponent,
      children:[
        { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
        { path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent },
        { path: '*', redirectTo: 'admin/login' }
      ]
  },
```

The above code is not working but, I want to archive some think like this.
(Note: See last children path in both case)

Comment: You seem to be handling them already?

Comment: Should that be two asterisks for a wildcard path?

Comment: current code not working. i have tried with (**) it work but only when redirectTo: '' ". i have to set redirectTo: ''admin/login" some thing like this.

Comment: GOT IT, `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/admin/login' }` have to set full path starting with "/". Please welcome if there any better idea.

Comment: Yes. Without the first slash it it a relative route.

Comment: Hi DeborahK Without the slash not working getting error.

Answer (score -1):

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/admin/login' }
```

Start with "/" and set full path in your redirectTo.